# frama-c / ACSL / WP : Cardinality of a set

Tags: frama-c, acsl

I often use cardinality of sets in others formal specifications and I wondering if it was possible to use it in ACSL with WP frama-c plugin.

For example, it seems clearer to me to write 
`assumes card({*a, *b, *c}) == 3`
rather than
`assumes *a != *b && *a != *c && *b != *c`

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I found a solution (a slow one I warn you, had to change the timeout from 10 seconds to 30 seconds just for the following example). Also it is broken in Frama-C version Calcium claiming that it can't find the Qed library (the bug appears to be in attempting to call a `logic boolean` type Frama-C function). It works properly in Frama-C version Chlorine (didn't test other versions).

```
/* "set" appears to be a reserved word in frama-c */

/*@ predicate full_card{L}(unsigned int* the_set, integer set_size) =
  \forall integer a, b; 0 <= a < set_size && 0 <= b < set_size && a != b ==> the_set[a] != the_set[b];
*/

/*@ logic boolean in_set_bool{L}(unsigned int* the_set, integer set_size, unsigned int element) =
  set_size == 0 ? \false : element == the_set[0] || in_set_bool(the_set + 1, set_size - 1, element);
*/

/*@ logic integer card{L}(unsigned int* the_set, integer set_size) =
  set_size == 0 ? 0 : (
    in_set_bool(the_set + 1, set_size - 1, the_set[0])
      ? card(the_set + 1, set_size - 1)
      : card(the_set + 1, set_size - 1) + 1);
*/

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  unsigned int set[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
  unsigned int set_size = 3;

  /*@ assert full_card(&set[0], set_size); */
  /*@ assert card(&set[0], set_size) == 3; */

  unsigned int set_two[] = { 3, 2, 1, 3 };
  unsigned int set_two_size = 4;

  /*@ assert card(&set_two[0], set_two_size) == 3; */
  /*@ assert !full_card(&set_two[0], set_two_size); */
}
```

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answer. If I understand correctly: the ACSL language does not propose natively the possibility to express a cardinal of a set. You have to build the solution yourself. As I understand it, recursive logical definitions are not very well handled by SMT solvers. Maybe that explains why proof takes time. Is there an already proved axiomatic library specifying the main abstract data structures and their properties ? It might be an effective solution